# How to serve GZipped assets with Jammit + Heroku + Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, heroku, jammit

I have made a webapp and deployed it to Heroku in Rails 2.3

I have also compressed all the files and uploaded to Cloudfront.

Now Heroku is serving all the static assets correctly but not the .gz version that Jammit created.

My PageSpeed would be excellent otherwise but due to the Gzip compressions it is 10 points short.

If anybody can tell me how I can leverage the GZip compression it would be of great help.

My site is at www.weddings9.com in case you want to check the gz assets.

Comment: Did you configure your assets server to be CloudFront instead of your own website?

Answer (score 0):

I forked a great project called Cloudfront Asset host that helps deploy your assets to Cloudfront and use them within a rails app (including regular and GZipped versions):

https://github.com/wpeterson/cloudfront_asset_host